# Understanding Firebase Cloud Firestore Billing

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to understand Firestore's billing but don't understand exactly what a read/write/delete request is.

If I delete 100,000 items in a single request does that count as 1 delete request or 100,000 delete request?

Also, if a single query returns 250 rows (documents?) does that count as a single read or 250 read requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read and write operations are billed **per document affected**.  So, your examples would incur the cost of 100,000 deletes and 250 reads.